# Is my trigger doing a batch, or one at a time?

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

I have a trigger class that interacts with Opportunities and creates a Task for each. But I don't know if the trigger is working on a batch of Opportunities or working on that individually.

Here's the code:

```
trigger OpportunityAfterInsert on Opportunity (after Insert) {

/* Opportunity Multiple Entries for Same Contact update Logic */     
 try{
    if(CallStratergyTasks.callStratergyCreateTaskOpportunityInsert == true)
    {
        List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(opportunity opp : Trigger.New)
        {
           if(opp.stageName == GlobalOrgConstant.NEWSTATUS || opp.stageName == GlobalOrgConstant.INPROGRESS)
          {
            oppList.add(opp);
          }
        }
        if(!oppList.isEMpty())
        {
            CallStratergyTasks callStratergy = new CallStratergyTasks();
            callStratergy.createCallStratergyTasks(oppList);
            CallStratergyTasks.callStratergyCreateTaskOpportunityInsert = false;
        }     
     }
    }
    Catch(Exception e){
        system.debug('Error Occurred****'+e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to understand, exactly? It's hard to tell where you need deeper understanding.

Comment: First, thanks for editing my code. I was mid-edit when it told me you already did it.

Comment: Second, I'm trying to understand is how this trigger works with the Opportunities our environment creates. The for loop makes it look like it works on them in a batch, going from opp to opp. But I think it might work on one opp, then the trigger is done, is opened again by another opp, then closes again, and so on.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trigger appears "Bulkified" meaning it will work on one Opportunity as well as multiple opportunities efficiently. How many opps it works on is a function of the Entry point of the trigger. If via UI, it is typically one opp, if via batch or other API/code processes it *may* be bulk (multiple records)

For example, if I pasted the code in the developer console execute anonymous window:

```
database.update(
   [ Select Id From Opportunity]
);
```

your trigger would be working on all opportunities (bulk)

however if I used the following or if I just clicked edit and save in the UI

```
database.update(
   [ Select Id From Opportunity Limit 1]
);
```

your trigger would be working on 1 opportunity.

Basically it comes down to what caused the trigger to fire in the first place as to if it will be working on one or many records *which is why you should always design your trigger to handle multiple records - bulkify*

Some reading:

[Best Practices to Bulkify your code](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code)

[Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)

> In API version 20.0 and earlier, if a Bulk API request causes a
>   trigger to fire, each chunk of 200 records for the trigger to process
>   is split into chunks of 100 records. In Salesforce API version 21.0
>   and later, no further splits of API chunks occur. If a Bulk API
>   request causes a trigger to fire multiple times for chunks of 200
>   records, governor limits are reset between these trigger invocations
>   for the same HTTP request.

Comment: Ah, I guess my first link does have related info, I just didn't see it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - As does mine, I just could not figure out which part to pull in as I thought it was all relevant. Either way I believe between all of us the OP should have what they need lol

Comment: Thank you Eric and Adrian, I will find out how our Leads are entered into our environment and how they turn into Opportunities. This has been really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read through some pages in the **`Apex Developer Guide`**.

- **[Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)**
  This page doesn't address your question specifically but has a lot of helpful information. Basically you should read through *all* the pages under this category.
- **[Bulk Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bulk.htm)**

  > All triggers are *bulk triggers* by default, and can process multiple records at a time. You should always plan on processing more than one record at a time.
- **[Trigger and Bulk Request Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm)**

  > A common development pitfall is the assumption that trigger invocations never include more than one record. Apex triggers are optimized to operate in bulk, which, by definition, requires developers to write logic that supports bulk operations.

Every trigger you write faces the possibility it will encounter multiple records. If the size of the record collection is more than 200, your trigger will be "batched" into chunks of 200.

Answer (score 3):

Triggers will work on records depending on how they are updated in a given context.

For example, if you update 1 opportunity, then the trigger will process one record. If you update a List of opportunities, then the trigger will process those all at once.

The caveat, however, is that a trigger will process up to 200 records at a time, but you don't really have to do anything to make this happen (SFDC does it internally for you). This means that if you update 3000 opportunities (in a List, all at once), your trigger code will be executed 15 times (200x15). This is important when you consider your code for the CPU time other governor limits.

This is why you always have to bulkify your triggers (and your code looks like it's doing that already), because you don't know if you are getting one or many records in a given transaction.